# Getting Error while receiving TriggerMessage from OCPP CMS server

Tags: python, json, content-management-system

Iam designing a OCPP simulator based on PyPi OCPP v1.6J. I successfully sent Bootnotification, HeartBeat and Status notification to the OCPP CMS server. But while receiving any message from CMS server iam getting error in my console.

I tried to give TriggerMessage (Heartbeat) from CMS server but my simulated charge point is not accepting the request. It throughs some error. The code snippet is attached below

```
class ChargePoint(cp):

    @on(Action.TriggerMessage)
    def on_trigger_message(self, requestedMessage, conectorId, **kwargs):
        return call.TriggerMessagePayload(
            connector_id = 1,
            requested_message = "Heartbeat"
        )
        return call_result.TriggerMessagePayload(
            status = TriggerMessageStatus.accepted
            
        )
```

And the error message is attached below

```
C:\Python38>python ocppclientsteve.py
Connected to SteVe CMS server.
Error while handling request '<Call - unique_id=f95390e4-a751-4bbb-8a41-abed33b29ca8, action=TriggerMessage, payload={'requestedMessage': 'Heartbeat', 'connectorId': 1}>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ocpp\charge_point.py", line 185, in _handle_call
    response = handler(**snake_case_payload)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ocpp\routing.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_trigger_message() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'requestedMessage' and 'conectorId'
Error while handling request '<Call - unique_id=d12e5c40-f155-4d49-bd68-38f9c9fd074b, action=TriggerMessage, payload={'requestedMessage': 'Heartbeat', 'connectorId': 1}>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ocpp\charge_point.py", line 185, in _handle_call
    response = handler(**snake_case_payload)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\ocpp\routing.py", line 33, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_trigger_message() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'requestedMessage' and 'conectorId'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the library here.

The library uses snake_case for all attributes. Like this:

```py
class ChargePoint(cp):

    @on(Action.TriggerMessage)
    def on_trigger_message(self, requested_message, connector_id, **kwargs):
        return call.TriggerMessagePayload(
            connector_id = 1,
            requested_message = "Heartbeat"
        )
        return call_result.TriggerMessagePayload(
            status = TriggerMessageStatus.accepted
            
        )
```